# Would more windings or bigger diameter makes a spring stronger?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, material-science, spring

Imagine I have 2 springs of the same length and material, thickness of wire is the same too. Spring A has twice as much windings and spring B has bigger windings about double the diameter of A. I am wondering which spring is stronger, I think should be more windings but that's just my intuition.

Comment: Define _stronger_. You mean a higher spring constant (which we usually call $k$)?

Comment: @noah: but the material and thickness of wire is fixed so the spring constant should be same for both A and B, no?

Comment: No, the spring constant depends on the material but also the geometry of the spring. If you have assumed $k$ to be equal, what did you mean by _stronger_?

Comment: @noah: I thinking super hard but then wouldn't the spring constant varies along the spring if geometry plays a part, no?

Comment: That can be addressed in an answer, here I'm just trying to clarify what you had in mind when you asked whether one of them was _stronger_. Describe the concept you were thinking of when writing the question.

Comment: The design of a spring is more of an engineering function because it's related to properties of materials and distributions of forces rather than fundamentals of the mechanics of a spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (k) value for a spring will depend on the flexibility of the material. It should increase with a larger diameter wire. The (k) should be inversely proportional to the number of turns, but the dependence on the diameter of each loop would be more difficult to predict.

Answer (score 0):

Rather non-intuitively a coil spring when 'stretched' puts the 'wire' of the coils into torsion.

When the same spring is 'wound up' (twisted) then the wire is bent.

In both cases the deflection depends on the length of the wire and hence on the diameter of the coil.

However - if you look at the deflection of a beam with point load on end (i.e. the bending option) the relationship is proportional to l^3

Whereas the torsional deflection is linearly dependant on the length of the 'twisted' wire/beam - so k would be inversely proportional to diameter...